# Parse a floating-point value with a currency symbol and a thousands separator

Tags: vb.net

I have the following string values:

> EUR 40,582.00
>
> $29,098.30

I want to convert them to decimal values.

I've tried `Decimal.Parse` and it doesn't work. My vb.net code:

```
Decimal.Parse("EUR 40,582.00", NumberStyles.Currency)
Decimal.Parse("$29,098.30", NumberStyles.Currency)
```

What is the correct way to convert this string values to decimal values?

Comment: Why don't you first parse the string to remove any chars which are not digits or decimal separator chars and then do your cast?

Comment: How do I remove all chars from the string?

Comment: @yu_ominae - that is NOT good practice. a lot of string parsing and cater for many currencies too as well as culture problems.

Comment: The problem is that I need to parse different currencies.

Comment: right - firstly you need to provide AllowCurrencySymbol in the NumberStyles (or them together i.e NumberStyles.Currency | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol). Maybe also try NumberStyles.Any too.

Comment: also take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx(v=vs.110).aspx and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953037/problem-parsing-currency-text-to-decimal-type

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I know, but I don't see how that is going to work if his strings are not using the currency symbols.

Comment: I've found this to work: `Regex.Replace("EUR 40,582.00", "[^\d|\.\-]", "")`

Comment: I've tried `Decimal.Parse("EUR 40,582.00", NumberStyles.Any)` and `Decimal.Parse("EUR 40,582.00", NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol)` and it doesn't work. I still get the error `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Answer (score 0):

read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

```
The Currency ("C") Format Specifier.<br>
    123.456 ("C", en-US) -> $123.46<br>
    123.456 ("C", fr-FR) -> 123,46 €<br>
```

Read about : **FormatCurrency**

read: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_format_currency.html

you must use a Case or something by CurrencySymbol

```
NumberFormatInfo MyNFI = new NumberFormatInfo();
MyNFI.NegativeSign = "-";
MyNFI.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
MyNFI.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
MyNFI.CurrencySymbol = "$";

decimal d = decimal.Parse("$29,098.30", NumberStyles.Currency, MyNFI);
```

Comment: What if I have multiple CurrencySymbol?