# C# | Grabbing JSON from URL cannot convert string to int

Tags: c#, json

I have a piece of code, which should grab info from a URL. Get the value called `lowest_price` and then parse it into a variable, but there is a `$` sign in the JSON so I had to remove it and after that I can't Parse the JSON correctly.

My code:

```
var tokenPrice = JObject.Parse(steamMarket).ToString().Replace("$", " ");
double marketPrice = tokenPrice["lowest_price"];
```

JSON

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"$5.61","volume":"6","median_price":"$5.61"}
```

Error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem parsing currency text to decimal type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953037/problem-parsing-currency-text-to-decimal-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double marketPrice = double.Parse(JObject.Parse(steamMarket)["lowest_price"].ToString().Replace("$", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

tokenPrice["lowest_price"] is a string and c# will not automatically convert types for you.

```
var tokenPrice = JObject.Parse(steamMarket);
double marketPrice = double.Parse(tokenPrice["lowest_price"].ToString().Replace("$", ""));
```

Comment: That gives tokenPrice the value of Replace which is a string. You cannot index into a string using a string. It has the same problem as the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
string json = "{\"success\":true,\"lowest_price\":\"$5.61\",\"volume\":\"6\",\"median_price\":\"$5.61\"}";
var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
double tokenPrice = double.Parse((string )jObject["lowest_price"], NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```