# .Net: Converting currency formatted value to a decimal value using String.Replace

Tags: c#, parsing, casting, decimal, currency

I have a value that is formatted in currency format and displayed in a textbox. I need to pick it and convert it into decimal. e.g. I have  `$1,633.75` **as string** and want to cast it as a decimal to save it in the db.
There are questions and some answers available on them already, but they all suggest more complex UDF etc to solve the problem.

Question is, why cannot we use the replace method on a string to remove commas (",") and "$" and simply use decimal.Parse?

Say tbAmountPaid is  `$1,633.75`

What is downside of just doing:

`decimal.Parse(tbAmountPaid.Text.Replace(",","").Replace("$",""))`

to get decimal type `1633.75` value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem parsing currency text to decimal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953037/problem-parsing-currency-text-to-decimal-type)

Comment: You may need to re-read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); step 1 of which is research. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thank you, I asked a different question regarding a problem already discussed in numerous posts as I mentioned. I cannot post a comment therefore I have to post a question to get thoughts around it.

Comment: Note that your lack of reputation does not prevent you from providing an *answer* to another question (as long as it *is* an answer). So you could offer this approach as an alternative answer to one of those questions, and see what comments people offer.

Comment: Why not use a mask on the textbox?

Comment: Well it does allow me to post an answer, even thought I have not answered any questions in the past. Moreover, What I have posted here is not an answer, it is more of a question

Answer (score 0):

Downside is that hardcoding. You never know the culture and the format in which string is written. There could be multiple bugs in the string itself. If you do hard coding you may end up having a bug in your code

I recommend you to use the format provider. I took code from here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Decimal_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_

```
string value;
decimal number;
NumberStyles style;
CultureInfo provider;

value = "$1,633.75";
style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;
provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
number = Decimal.Parse(value, style, provider);
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converted to {1}.", value, number);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you're not asking how to do it, you're asking *"why not do it this way?"*...

1. Your alternative takes more effort to type than the correct solution,
2. More effort for the computer to process,
3. More memory usage (since strings are immutable),
4. Compiles to larger IL,
5. Your approach is culture specific. Some cultures use dot for the thousand separator and comma for the decimal place, let alone a different currency symbol.

Turning the question around, what do you feel is *better* about your approach?

Comment: 1. I am not expecting my code code to be used for a multiple cultures.  2. It is just simpler and quicker to write when coding, instead of creating a UDF and passing a value to it and then removing the formatting, converting it and returning the value. I might be wrong but this is the reason I needed to know a bit more as why not this way. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying it's easier to do `decimal.Parse(tbAmountPaid.Text.Replace(",", "").Replace("$", ""))` than it is to do `decimal.Parse(tbAmountPaid.Text, NumberStyles.Currency)` (I don't know why you think you need a UDF). If your goal is *"just simpler and quicker to write when coding"* then write an extension method to encapsulate it. That way you can write it correctly once and reuse it across your codebase.